# Cannot getxfa data from form pdf using pdftk

Tags: pdftk

I want to extract XFA data from PDF using PDFTK library or using command line.

PDFTK provided drop_xfa but i want to extract xfa from form pdf. 
How i will achieve this using pdftk.

I have tried or search so many thing on google but not getting proper result.

Please suggest any thing will be appreciated.

Comment: I have solution in java using itext library. But i want to extract xfa using php.